# Finding an alternate generating curve

Tags: 3d, elliptic-curves, curves, solid-of-revolution

[image]

Using $r(x)  = \frac{(1-2x)}{3}$

my first generating curve is

$y^2 + z^2 = \left(\frac{1-2x}{3}\right)^2$

I'm stuck on finding another generating curve as $x^2$ cannot be isolated to make a generating curve that revolves about $z$ axis or $y$ axis. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: someone send help...lol

Comment: The surface is not rotationally symmetric about any line except the $x$-axis, so it will have to still be a revolution around the $x$-axis. I'm guessing the question wants $z=-(1-2x)/3$ or $z=|(1-2x)/3|$, but arguably the curve $2x+3y=1$ in the $xy$-plane is distinct.

Comment: Thank you; I will ask my prof about this tmr and update back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it guys, the correct answer was just to use the xy trace formula and have it revolve around the x-axis so

y = (1 - 2x)/3